# Permanently place Desktop gadget slightly outside of desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

If you drag a [Desktop gadget](http://www.doozygadgets.com/images/2012.07/Latest-Windows-7-Desktop-Gadgets-231053389661698.png)  slightly outside your normal desktop borders, Windows will revert the position back to normal on your next logon. How can I prevent this?

<sub>Gadget was dragged 2-3cm to the right to gain some space</sub>
[image]
<sub>After a new logon the Gadget was positioned back</sub>
[image]

Comment: this is supposed to work even for gadgets even after restart. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/disable-the-mouse-drag-window-arranging-feature-in-windows-7/  untested.  “Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen”

Comment: Good to know, but completely disabling Aero Snap wasn't what I'm looking for.